# Unable to power on Raspberry Pi 400 by shorting GPIO pins 5 and 6 (WAKE_ON_GPIO)

Tags: gpio

I have a Raspberry Pi 400 and am unable to get my Pi to wake when I short GPIO pins 5 and 6. I tried installing the latest version of the bootloader using raspi-config and checked my eeprom file to see that WAKE_ON_GPIO is set to 2 as the docs say that "Pi 400 has a dedicated power button which operates even if the processor is switched off. This behaviour is enabled by default, however, WAKE_ON_GPIO=2 may be set to use an external GPIO power button instead of the dedicated power button."

I have tried powering up by shorting GPIO pins 5 and 6 after shutting down the pi with "sudo shutdown -H now" with no luck.

I have also tried powering up by shorting GPIO pins 5 and 6 after shutting down by editing /boot/config.txt, putting in "dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown,gpio_pin=3" and then shorting GPIO pins 5 and 6.

Has anybody successfully got their Raspberry Pi 400 to start up using the WAKE_ON_GPIO functionality (shorting GPIO pins 5 and 6)?

Answer (score 0):

This "feature" does not work on the Pi400 because it has additional circuitry to turn power off which completely disables the SOC.

> Update: A [2020-11-24 change](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/blob/master/firmware/release-notes.md) "If a button on GPIO3 really is requried(sic) then it can be re-enabled by setting WAKE_ON_GPIO=2 but that will consume more power."
> *NOTE It is unclear why anyone would want to do this*.

The same applies on the Pi4 if you disable power on shutdown using POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1

Comment: I can see how that might be the case, but the documentation at [Bootloader Configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md) says _"Pi 400 has a dedicated power button which operates even if the processor is switched off. This behaviour is enabled by default, however, WAKE_ON_GPIO=2 may be set to use an external GPIO power button instead of the dedicated power button."_ which seems to suggest that this feature works on the Pi400. Do you definitively know otherwise?

Comment: @Bryan I don't have a Pi400 and this was not in the documentation when I last read it. The original boot code is a Video Core service which requires the SOC to be powered which was the case on shutdown even though the CPU is halted. The Foundation is always changing code but I still don't see how this would be done.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something has been badly designed on the PI 400 since it appears no-one has been successful in waking it up with GPIO pins. A shame that it's not possible to connect an external button.

The only way I found for starting PI-400, without the use of the button "F10", is to turn off the power and then turn it back on.